# Is the iOS 50mb file size limit is the same all over the world?

Tags: iphone, size, limit, archive, ota

1.)As I know the app size is counting the zipped IPA file, is there any country have different file size limit on OTA downloads or all use the same 50mb limit?

2.)for my another app, after I archive, the 'Estimated App Store Size:' writes 1.17GB.
When I reveal the file in finder, the .xcarchive file is 665.5MB, after I compressed the .xcarchive in finder, the zip shows 598.3MB, so which one is the actual App Size that use to compare the 50MB?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I have no idea. But it is Apple that controls the size allowed, not the operators (there was never any delay when they changed from 20mb -> 50 mb). So most likely it is global, or close to.

The bundle is encrypted when submitted to the app store, which removes most potential for compression that is possible for a plain-text bundle. Usually the final size will be somewhere between the XCode estimate and the plain-text zip version.